# How can I show my latest 3 tweets on my website?

Tags: jquery, twitter, web

I haven't updated my website in a long time and just recently noticed my tweets were not getting changed on my website and was instead just getting loading...a lot of people say to use the twitter widget but I was wondering if there was another way in JQuery?

This is the code I was using:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  jQuery(function($){
    $("#ticker").tweet({
      username: "username example",
      page: 1,
      avatar_size: 32,
      count: 10,
      loading_text: "loading ..."
    }).bind("loaded", function() {
      var ul = $(this).find(".tweet_list");
      var ticker = function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
          ul.find('li:first').animate( {marginTop: '-4em'}, 500, function() {
            $(this).detach().appendTo(ul).removeAttr('style');
          });
          ticker();
        }, 5000);
      };
      ticker();
    });
  });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure it is supported in the latest Twitter API version. I think the current is 1.1